# Bash: can't type 'e' or I'll get infinitely repeating 'H's

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell

At my workplace, there are several independent networks I work with, all running various versions of RedHat Linux 4, 5, and 6.

On one of those networks, I can't use bash (or, as I'm finding out, anything that uses the bash front-end like python, gdb, etc) because when I try to type this:

```
> exit
```

I instead get:

```
> HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH<control-C>
```

Until I hit control-C (for bash or gdb) or, in another terminal, do a killall python for python.

My primary working shell is tcsh, but I use bash for all my scripting. I also drop into the shell interactively sometimes to do simple loops and the like. Luckily, 'exit' is in my history so I can use the up arrow to get it back and exit.

Just to be clear: this only happens when I run these programs interactively. It does not matter if I started the shell:

```
> bash

> bash --login

> env bash --login

> env bash
```

This happens whether I remove my bash_profile and bashrc files or not. AFAIK, there's nothing in the system's profile that would cause this.

I am completely at a loss how to even go about finding this! I'd GREATLY appreciate any help anybody can offer!

TIA!

Comment: Is there some `.inputrc` in effect? Use `bind -p` to find out. Does `reset` help?

Comment: Does the "E" key act funny in any other programs? Is it a weird keyboard, or location setting? Does swapping keyboards with a different machine change anything?

Comment: You can "exit" by pressing up arrow and finding "exit" in your history, as you point out.  You can also exit by pressing EOF on a blank line.  Press Ctrl-C (to quickly blank your line) and Ctrl-D.  This doesn't solve your problem, but it will help speed up your workaround and is just generally nice to know.

Comment: Are you a system administrator?  Can you tell whether this happens to all users, or just one?  Does this also affect other shells (sh, dash, zsh, etc.--- maybe try what is in /etc/shells)  Does this happen if you run bash from within xterm?

Comment: @Xen2050: It didn't act funny in any other programs. Another thing I forgot to mention was that I was on a Windows machine (ick) using X-Win to connect to the Linux machine. My primary shell, the intel debugger, nedit, kate, etc were all fine - just a few things were broken. In this particular environment, swapping keyboards is... not feasible.

Comment: @TOOGAM: I always forget about that. I tend not to think about that in the things that allow me to type exit. I do, however, use that in older versions of python where 'exit' is a string telling you to instead give it an EOF character. Also, it does not happen to other users, just me.

Comment: @choroba: You are a life-saver. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, with the help of a suggestion from choroba, I figured it out.

In this environment, they have the idiotic policy of nearly forcing everybody to source all the same resource files in addition to their own configuration. One day, they changed something and broke half of our shells.

In the process of trying to fix this, I put print statements in the various profiles and resource files so that I could see which ones were even being run to track down why things were broken.

I didn't realize that, unlike every other file ending in 'rc', the '.inputrc' doesn't get RUN, it gets PARSED. And it gets parsed strangely. So, I had this in the .inputrc:

```
echo "Hello..."
```

Which somehow got interpreted by the binding system (which apparently only bash, gdb, python, and maybe some other things I hadn't yet used actually look at) as 'when the user types e, print H infinitely'. Which is clearly what I meant.

I now have a functional bash, python, and gdb! Thank you!

Comment: Apparently it's binding "e" to "Hello...", but of course the second letter of that is "e", so that gets turned into "Hello...", and then it just keeps doing that over and over. Try running `bind 'z "1234 z"'`, then press "z" and watch the fun.

Comment: Ahhhhh! That explains it!

Answer (score 3):

a quick hack,

```
$ i () { printf "%x" 14;}
```

or

```
$ i () { printf \\x65;}
$ l`i`ss
Missing filename ("less --help" for help)
$ `i`xit
```

another hack,

```
$ E^b^[l
```

This makes E lower.

This might help,

```
$ bind -m `i`macs
```

Comment: This was downvoted to -1.  Though this doesn't answer the question, I recognize it is a workaround that may be helpful.  The formatting also makes it long enough that it might not have easily fit into a comment.  I upvoted this as a useful contribution.  I will add that $( and ) can be used instead of back-quotes, and may be more easily nestable.  Although, like my earlier comment, this approach really hasn't answered the key question, of why iAdjunct is even experiencing the problem in the first place, or how to properly fix it.  That answer is still sought.

Comment: This is quite possibly the most hilarious thing I've ever read on stack-exchange. I literally burst out laughing. Then I showed a coworker/friend and he burst out laughing. Then I showed another coworker/friend (who is used to be totally abusing syntax to do dastardly deeds) and he looked at me like "oh no."

Comment: This actually was helpful: I was indeed able to poke around in bash because of this.